# Writting a DuckDB extension: how to return an integer from a scalar function

Tags: c++, database, duckdb

I am writting a DuckDB extension based on the official extension template. It contains an example function which accepts a string as input and returns another string:

```cpp
inline void ExampleScalarFun(DataChunk &args, ExpressionState &state, Vector &result) {
    auto &name_vector = args.data[0];
    UnaryExecutor::Execute<string_t, string_t>(
        name_vector, result, args.size(),
        [&](string_t name) {
            return StringVector::AddString(result, "The provided name is  "+name.GetString()+" ");;
        });
}
```

How to replace that with a function that returns an integer?

I was able to modify the function to take two integer inputs

```cpp
inline void Addition(DataChunk &args, ExpressionState &state, Vector &result) {
    auto &first_argument_vector = args.data[0];
    auto &second_argument_vector = args.data[1];
    BinaryExecutor::Execute<int, int, string_t>(
        first_argument_vector, second_argument_vector, result, args.size(),
        [&](int a, int b) {
            return StringVector::AddString(result, "We need to add together " + std::to_string(a)  + " and " + std::to_string(b)  + " ");;
        });
}
```

But I do not understand how to change the return type, because I do not know how to manipulate the `Vector &result` with anything else than the provided `StringVector::AddString`.

Also, what is the purpose of `BinaryExecutor`? If it is essentially just iterating over the inputs as a for loop would do, could I replace it with a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is pretty straightforward:

```cpp
static void Adittion(DataChunk &args, ExpressionState &state, Vector &result) {
    // Assumes args.data[0] and args.data[1] are the input vectors
    BinaryExecutor::Execute<double, double, double>(args.data[0], args.data[1], result, args.size(),
    [](double left, double right) {
        return left + right;
    });
}
```

So the lambda passed to the `BinaryExecutor::Execute` just needs to return the result and `BinaryExecutor::Execute` itself will handle putting it into the `result` vector.